# Is there a way to export Wordpress comments to a non-wordpress, HTML coded site?

Tags: comments, import, export

As the title says.

I would like to recreate a Wordpress.org website I have, as a HTML coded site. Would like to export wordpress comments and import them to my new, non-wordpress site. Would be great if I an also include the names of the commenters.

Thank you

Comment: How are you exporting the actual posts? Yes, they're all there in the database in the wp_comments table, with per-comment data in wp_commentmeta. You can also use the per-post comment RSS feed, which you'll find in meta tags in the HTML for each post page.

Comment: The actual posts, I won' t be exporting. I want to recreate the website off wordpress, so I can just copy the text and re-add the images. For the comments, how does that work, do I copy and paste the comments to where I want? What will happen to the commenter avatar/name etc?

Comment: Does the new site have a comment system, i.e. you want to put all of the comments into a different database? You can copy the data from WordPress's wp_comments and wp_commentmeta tables. By default Avatars will just be using Gravatar which is based on the md5sum of the commenter's email address, so all you need is the email address, unless you have a membership plugin or similar that's changed that.

Comment: But if you just want to copy and paste you probably want to copy and paste the HTML from your existing site's comment sections. If you want different HTML it might be easiest to edit the comment template on your site or a copy of the site and then copy the HTML from that. But then your new site won't support adding more comments.

Comment: @Rup, I want to create a new version of my website, outside of Wordpress, using HTML only because I don't like wordpress anymore. I'd like to copy the comments to the new, non-wordpress site, AND allow new comments, AND keep the gravatar/email addresses of the original commenters.

Comment: What are you planning to use for comments on the new site? Some other CMS, or a comment web app (e.g. Disqus, or you can use Facebook, etc.), or write something yourself? You probably want to choose or build that system, and then import your existing comments into it. If it's a well known system or CMS then chances are there will be a way to copy comments from WordPress into it. If you're building your own then you can just copy data from WordPress's database.

Comment: I have not decided on a platform yet, but definitely not facebook. Disqus might be okay, but it's only for a blog, nothing important so I want something free.

Comment: Update: Found a self hosted program that allows you to import Wordpress comments https://schnack.cool/#wordpress but unfortunately I have no idea how to use Github. Any pointers on this topic would also be appreciated.

Comment: Great. I don't see anything you need to do with GitHub, though, unless you want to add them as a possible authentication provider? The git clone and npm lines on that page should work fine, assuming the server you're going to host it on is set up with git and node.js, and you can set it up to automatically restart the schnick server on reboots / crashes etc. (you probably want to reverse proxy it into the main web server)

Comment: Sorry I meant I have no idea how to use Git or install Schnack